# Rails 4 - Admins editing another user's info

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want a simple system where users have three types (`user`, `admin` and `medic`) and the ones tagged `Admin` can "activate" other users' accounts so they can access certain privileges. I tried doing this with a simple button but I haven't found a way to do so.

The button for the code is:

```
<%= button_to "Change user Type to Medic", :method=> "activate_medic" %>
```

My activation method is as so:

```
def activate_medic
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@user.activated = true
if @user.save 
  flash[:info] = "Success"
end
```

end

And there's a `post 'users/activate_medic'` in my `routes.rb` file. 
However, pressing the button brings up:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/users/1"):
```

If I'm trying to edit user 1.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what I proposed in the original question, but: 
I allowed the Admin users to completely edit a given user's info and by proxy their user type and permissions:

Users controller:

```
        before_action :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]        
        def correct_user
          @user = User.find(params[:id])
          redirect_to(root_url) unless current_user?(@user) || current_user.type == "Admin"
        end
```

However, to avoid any user from just accessing their edit page and giving themselves admin rights, I edited the form to only allow Admins to see the field that edits their type:

```
  <% if @user.type == "Admin" %>
    <%= f.label :type, "User Type:" %>
    <%= f.text_field :type, class: 'form-control' %>
  <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The method option in link_to is meant to specify an HTTP verb, not the name of a custom method. Based on what you've provided, I would approach the problem like this:

```
button_to "Change user Type to Medic", activate_user_path(@user), method: :patch
```

And a dedicated controller:

```
class ActivateUserController

  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.activate
      flash[:info] = "Success"
    end
    redirect_to @user
  end
end
```

And a route:

```
resources :users do
  patch :activate, to: 'activate_user#update', as: :activate_user
end
```

And finally, move user behavior into the User model:

```
class User 

  def activate
    self.update_attribute!(:active, true)
  end
end
```

Comment: This seems to be giving me the error `undefined method 'activate_user_path'`

Comment: I suspect you copy and pasted the sample code, which was provided simply to illustrate a concept. Perhaps have a look at the Rails routing documentation here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Comment: It seems to be creating a `users_activate_users` route. Upon fixing the button to reflect this, I get an error and the log says: 
`ActionController::RoutingError (uninitialized constant ActivateUserController):`